# How to add a text file to a zip in one single command?

Tags: command-line, pipe, zip

I want a put a text file in a encrypted zip archive. I would currently use:

```
echo "<my text>" > file.txt
zip --encrypt myarchive.zip file.txt
```

**Is there a way to do the same thing in one single command without having to save a file?**

Comment: you can do `cmd1; cmd2` for single line.. not sure about single command

Comment: I see the pipe tag.May be he need a pipe-like command like 'create file' | 'encrypt&add to archive'.And if you just want to write one-line command,this: echo "<my text>" > file.txt&&zip --encrypt myarchive.zip file.txt should work for you.

Comment: What is the use case? The maintainer isn't going to thank you for complicating what is a very simple couple of commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
zip --encrypt myarchive.zip -j -FI <(echo message)
```